# How to express this route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-forms

I can't seem to access the show action from my nested controller. I am able to create an object, but the `redirect_to`  fails.

**routes.rb**

```
 blog_topic_posts POST   /blog/topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)  blog/posts#create
 edit_blog_topic_post GET    /blog/topics/:topic_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) blog/posts#edit
 blog_topic_post GET    /blog/topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      blog/posts#show
 PUT    /blog/topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      blog/posts#update
 DELETE /blog/topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      blog/posts#destroy
```

**new** and **create** actions:

```
def new
 @post = Post.new 
 @tag = @post.tags.build
end

def create
 @post = Post.new(params[:post])
 @post.user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
   if @post.save
    flash[:success] = 'Post was successfully created.'
    format.html { redirect_to([:blog, @topic, @post]) }
   else
    format.html { render action: :new }
   end
  end
 end
```

When I pass the above redirect it returns the routing error:

```
  NoMethodError in Blog::PostsController#create

  undefined method `blog_post_url' for #<Blog::PostsController:0x00000002ee34f8>

  {"utf8"=>"✓",
   "authenticity_token"=>"dN9feAsRVJal9P1YDtgEeHHwsP4yr3rZT1KBjgR57SI=",
   "post"=>{"title"=>"ban",
   "description"=>"bobobo",
   "content"=>"---- sequi- molestias- qui- veritatis- quasi- modi- praesentium- nesciunt- voluptates- exercitationem",
   "topic_id"=>"1",
   "tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"tag_name"=>"bank"}}},
   "commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

Can anyone explain why this route fails? And why it isn't looking for blog_topic_post_url? as an aside,the following redirect in the same controller works for PUT...

```
def update
 # loading in post object via before_filter
 if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
  flash[:success] = "Post was successfully updated."
  redirect_to blog_topic_post_url([@post.topic]) 
 else
  flash[:error] = "Post could not be saved."
  render :edit 
 end
end
```

Comment: What does your routes.rb file show?

Comment: @WaynnLue please see the routes, file. I decided to go with the conventional redirect from create and I am now receiving the error above instead.

Comment: figured it out. the route needed to be represented like so `redirect_to([:blog, @post.topic])` not like so `redirect_to([:blog, @topic, @post])`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. You should answer your question with that code and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The route function when:

```
redirect_to([:blog, @post.topic])
```

but not like so:

```
redirect_to([:blog, @topic, @post])
```

Which is identical to the `update` action. I do not need to load the `@topic` at this point in the creation of the post object as it is already set in the post object.